# Criar trigger after update na própria tabela e numa outra

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, trigger

De primeiro tenho uma tabela:

```
create table alecrim(
id_alecrim int not null auto_increment, 
sem_epi int not null unique,
p1 smallint,
p2 smallint,
p3 smallint,
p4 smallint,
p5 smallint, 
p6 smallint,  
p7 smallint,
p8 smallint,
p9 smallint,
totOvos int,
ano varchar(4),
primary key(id_alecrim)
) default charset = utf8;
```

E a tabela:

```
create table tb_indices_leste(
id_leste int not null auto_increment,
localidade varchar(30),
sem_epi int not null unique,
totOvos smallint,
pend tinyint,
ext tinyint,
ipo decimal(5,1),
ido decimal(5,1),
ano varchar(4),
primary key(id_leste)) default charset = utf8;
```

E quero criar um trigger com o objetivo de após um UPDATE na tabela ALECRIM o trigger "SETar" o campo totOvos com a soma dos valores dos campos p1+p2+...+p9, porém essa soma precisa ser da linha onde ouve o UPDATE e "SETar" o mesmo valor no campo totOvos da tabela tb_indices_alecrim na linha onde o valor da sem_epi seja igual ao valor da sem_epi de ALECRIM na qual sofreu o UPDATE. 
Alguém poderia me ajudar nisso?

Answer (score 1):

Basta utilizar o `BEFORE UPDATE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_alecrim_update BEFORE UPDATE 
ON alecrim
FOR EACH row
    SET NEW.totOvos = NEW.p1 + NEW.p2 + NEW.p3 + NEW.p4 + NEW.p5 + NEW.p6 + NEW.p7 + NEW.p8 + NEW.p9;
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado, Felipe Marinho! 
E se eu quiser colocar outro SET, basta colocar abaixo ou preciso criar delimitadores ou Blocos BEGIN/END?

Comment: @AmiraldoRodriguesFilho Você pode utilizar o mesmo `SET`, basta colocar uma vírgula, o nome da coluna, o símbolo de igual e o valor desejado, exemplo: `SET NEW.coluna1=valor1, NEW.coluna2=valor2`, etc.

Comment: Felipe Marinho No caso do outro SET, esqueci de especificar que seria em outra tabela! Na verdade seria esse SET na mesma tabela e outro para uma outra. Precisaria de delimitadores ou outro trigger?

Comment: @AmiraldoRodriguesFilho Qual a relação entre as duas tabelas? Qual linha da tabela `tb_indices_leste` deveria ser atualizada quando uma da `alecrim` fosse?

Comment: A relação é (1:N), pois o campo totOvos influencia os campos ipo,ido e totOvos da tabela tb_indices_leste e as linhas que tiverem o mesmo valor em sem_epi são as linhas que precisam sofrer as atualizações.

Comment: @AmiraldoRodriguesFilho `sem_api` seria uma *foreign key* da tabela `alecrim` na tabela `tb_indices_leste`? Seria isso?

Comment: tenho pouco conhecimentos em sql. Se for preciso fazer essas alterações, eu faço. Então para esse trigger funcionar preciso fazer essas relações nas tabelas?! Seria melhor definir o campo sem_epi  para ser primary keys e a foreing keys? Porque os outros campos pode sofrer alterações, mas a sem_epi não pode e é o campo em comum entre as tabelas.

Comment: @AmiraldoRodriguesFilho Como existe uma relação 1:N entre `alecrim` e `tb_indices_leste`, o ideal seria haver uma coluna (*foreign key*) em `tb_indices_leste` com o identificador do `alecrim` relacionado (ou uma outra tabela que guarde a relação). Sem isso, você não vai saber quais linhas deve alterar em `tb_indices_leste` quando alterar alguma linha em `alecrim`.